# Specifying which "this" to use in my Jquery .click function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, this

I'm having trouble wording this in a search and can't seem to find anything that explains the issue to me, so here I am in need of help!

Below is my JS:

```
    $(".container").hover(function() {
        $(this).next().slideDown(500);
        $(this).css("opacity", "0.5");
    });

    $(".overlay > img").click(function() {
        $(this).slideUp(500);
        $(this).hide(750);
        $(this).prev().css("opacity", "1.0");
    });
```

Although I should post my HTML, I think it's simple enough to explain. I have a content container (".container") which has a hover event to slideUp my overlay container (".overlay"). Once my overlay container is up, the user can click a small 'x' to close it (that's the img). However I have several of these container and overlay divs throughout my page, hence why I am using the "this" selector. How do I tell "this", in the .click function to ONLY refer to the ".overlay" class instead of the img. Currently it hides the 'x' image.

Thanks for any and all help!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).closest('.overlay');
```

This will send you back up the tree to the closest parent with `class='overlay'`, and you can act against that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent()
```

Should target the `.overlay`

Comment: Well, in this situation it would work. Otherwise $(this).closest('.overlay') could be used.